# JavaScript window.close not firing after clicked on PrettyPhoto

Tags: javascript, jquery, buttonclick, jquery-callback, prettyphoto

JavaScript event onClick close window not firing after clicking and viewing PrettyPhoto image.

HTML

```
<button type="button" onClick="closeWin()">Close Window</button>
```

JavaScript

```
function closeWin() {
    window.close();
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
        callback: function() {
            closeWin();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can close window by using `window.close();` only by setting "off" security flags

In firefox, you can do this by going into about:config, click  "I'll be careful, I promise" button and search for

```
dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows
```

You'll see that it was set to false.

Make that true, you can close window by using window.close()

But this gives security issues.

There is another solution for closing the window, you can close the window which you opened.

Check that here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ranganadh/bkCbH/)

Answer (score 2):

Got another answer for closing window

```
window.open('','_self');
self.close();
```

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ranganadh/MPHh3/show/)

Works in Chrome, Safari.

In FF, you need to change the `dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows` value to `true`